# Are pointers to allocated memory outside object's lifetime "invalid pointer[s]" or "pointer[s] to an object"?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++17

C++17 (draft N4659) [[basic.compound]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#compound-3) says:

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the null pointer value ([conv.ptr]) for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.

To which of these categories belong pointers to allocated memory outside the lifetime of objects, specifically the values of `a` at `// (1)` through `// (3)` and `b` at `// (4)` in the following program?

```
#include<new>
#include<algorithm>

struct S {
    ~S() { /* Non-trivial destructor */ }
};

struct T {
    ~T() { /* Non-trivial destructor */ }
};

int main() {
    void* a = operator new(std::max(sizeof(S), sizeof(T)));
    // (1)
    a = new(a) S;
    static_cast<S*>(a)->~S();
    // (2)
    a = new(a) T;
    static_cast<T*>(a)->~T();
    // (3)
    operator delete(a);   

    void* b = operator new(42);
    // (4)
    operator delete(b);
}
```

---

In my understanding a pointer value becomes invalid when deallocated, not when the life time of an object ends, but if the pointer values are "*pointer[s] to an object*", to *which* object do they point?

Comment: A pointer to memory becomes invalid when that memory is deallocated.   A pointer to an object becomes invalid when the object ceases to exist.   For a type with a destructor, an instance of that type (aka an object) ceases to exist when its destructor completes.   In a delete expression that destructs an object, and then releases memory, any pointer to the object will be invalid when the destructor is done, and any pointer to its underlying memory will be invalid when the memory is released (e.g. the `operator delete()` function returns).

Comment: AFAIK, `operator new` returns a pointer to the first byte of a block of memory that has been allocated. You could consider the note in your link "Note: A pointer to void does not have a pointer-to-object type, however, because void is not an object type.  — end note". `a` and `b` still point to memory. Even after destruction of the objects. The destructor does not call `delete` for the allocated memory. Maybe it's 'officially' a "pointer to object type" in all cases, but you're combining concepts here by using `<new>`, which reintroduces C-style `malloc` and `free`-like allocation.

Comment: @JHBonarius The sentence before that does however say that `void*` is an "*object  pointer type*" and the quoted passage talks about every value of "*pointer type*", which I assumed to be a supset of "*object pointer type*". I am fully aware that `operator new` does return a pointer to allocated memory and that the destructor call does not deallocate it. `<new>` is included in order to make the non-allocating placement-new available. `std::free` and `std::malloc` are declared in `<cstdlib>`, not `<new>`.

Comment: @Peter "*A pointer to an object becomes invalid when the object ceases to exist.*": That is basically my question. Note however that "*invalid pointer value*" is a defined term and that [\[basic.stc\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#stc-4) would disallow passing an *invalid pointer value* to a deallocation function, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, but they effectively do the same thing.... `<new>` has a nice layer, so that a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown, instead of returning NULL.

Comment: You're frolicking under the hood of C++ and expect to apply language theory to it. From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) : operator new *can* be called explicitly as a regular function, **but in C++, new is an operator with a very specific behavior**: An expression with the new operator, first calls function operator new (i.e., this function) with the size of its type specifier as first argument, and if this is successful, it then automatically initializes or constructs the object (if needed). Finally, the expression evaluates as a pointer to the appropriate type.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the notion that one is invalid while the other is valid, or that it is possible to obtain an invalid pointer from a valid one (or vice versa).    In a delete expression, a `T *` becomes invalid from when the destructor is done (e.g. using that pointer to call a member function of the object gives undefined behaviour) but the `void *` remains valid until the memory is released (i.e. `operator delete()` returns).

Comment: @Peter In that interpretation the pointers I mention in my program (all `void*` and pointing to allocated storage) would *not* have *invalid pointer value*s and then would have to be by elimination of other choices "*pointer[s] to an object*" or do you think the quoted sentence doesn't even apply?

Comment: @JHBonarius I want to understand the details of the C++ standard, which I hope is at least somewhat unambiguous in its written language. (Therefore the `language-lawyer` tag.) I am fully aware of the behavior of *new-expression*s described in your quote. I see nothing preventing me from calling `operator new` directly though (not the same as using a *new-epression*) and using that memory later through a `void*` in my program to create different objects with placement new's, as I did in my example. I want to understand what parts of the standard apply inbetween these objects' existence.

Comment: @uneven_mark    After passing a void pointer to `operator delete()` it is invalid (on return from `operator delete()`).

Comment: @Peter Yes, I think that is clear, it is exactly what [\[basic.stc\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#stc-4) is saying, but I am specifically asking about immediately *before* that call.

Comment: Immediately before that call, the `void *` will be valid.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that is my understanding as well, but the question is, how this can be reconciled with the standard passage I quoted in my question. If it is not an invalid value, it must be pointer to an object, but that does not seem right, especially for `b` in my example, because there is no object.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what a ptr points to (pls see all my Q re: ptr). And while you are there, please define what the heck an lvalue is... whether an object can exist when its life does not...

Comment: @Peter "_A pointer to an object becomes invalid when the object ceases to exist_" What is the existence of an object? It is its lifetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To which of these categories belong pointers to allocated memory outside the lifetime of objects, specifically the values of `a` at `// (1)` through `// (3)` and `b` at `// (4)` in the following program?

Pointer values returned from allocation functions (`a` at `// (1)` and `b` at `// (4)`)  are not currently specified and it is barely possible to classify them according to the taxonomy in [basic.compound]/3, see https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/4NQawIytVzM/eMKo2AJ9BwAJ

> In my understanding a pointer value becomes invalid when deallocated, not when the life time of an object ends, but if the pointer values are "pointer[s] to an object", to which object do they point?

To the object they pointed to when the object was alive.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I assume that also kind of leaves open what exactly I am allowed to do with the pointer returned from `operator new`, e.g. whether I am always allowed to copy/pass it around (implementation-defined for invalid pointers) or cast it to other object pointer types (allowed outside lifetime of objects for specific destination types).

Comment: "To the object they pointed to when the object was alive." <== no, to the memory space that was allocated. The objects were each assigned in that memory space `new(a)`, so they are created inside that same space. And just just explained that pointers returned from allocation functions are not specified, so why say this?

Comment: _no, to the memory space that was allocated_ [This](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#footnote-54) footnote implies that a pointer can _point to_ an object not within its lifetime.

Comment: yeah, ok, true... but `operator new()` is en exception to this, as the resulting pointer points to the first byte of an allocated part of memory that has "never" been occupied by an object in the first place... so it's a bit of a chicken-egg story... It seems like we have to reason until the reality fits the standard... This is reverse...I think the standard is just incomplete: its too strict.

Answer (score -4):

All C++ standard are an **abject mess** when it comes to basic runtime concept.

What is an lvalue? It needs to be able to refer to a not yet created object. (Same for pointers.)

When do not created object exist? Do they appear just before they are needed?

**To me the best approach would have been to assume all object types exist everywhere in memory where they fit.** Many people here told me that was insane and contradictory yet no one ever pointed to a contradiction.

Comment: "*Do they appear just before they are needed?*": I think this is basically the idea behind proposal [P0593r5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r5.html) which might still become part of C++20.

Comment: @uneven_mark I yet can't make sense of existing std prose re: lifetime of an object, storage that an obj will occupy. Since when can you use the **future**? Seems to me obj have existence, and during **that existence a lifetime is defined**.